# Adding Dynamic Javascript with jQuery stops previously added from functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds an draggable element to a form.

This works really well until I add another - plus its script - and then the previous on just stops responding. Both scripts are present in the DOM.

Why did the first one stop?

I have tried

```
$.noConflict()
```

and

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

but this just stops it working totally.

My script that adds the draggable element is shown below.

```
 function createTextBox() {
     //Random name for out text box. users dont see this.

     var textBoxName = 'tb_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
     var html_script;

     html_script="<div id='draggable" + textBoxName + "' style='position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;'>" +
              "<img src='../../Images/next.png' style='cursor: pointer;'/><img style='cursor: pointer;' src='../../Images/delete.png' onclick=\"RemoveTextBox('" + textBoxName + "')\"/>" +
              "<a href='#' class='data_field ui-draggable ui-resizable' id='draggable" + textBoxName + "'></a>" +
              "<textarea rows='5' cols='80' title='Text Box' data-tooltip='Tool'" +
              " data-width='100'" +
              " data-height='20'" +
              " data-topx='10'" +
              " data-topy='10" +
              " data-multiline='true'" +
              " data-hidden='false'" +
              " data-type='textBox'" +
              " name='" + textBoxName + "'" +
              " id='" + textBoxName + "'" +
              " class='data_field ui-widget-content ui-corner-all'" +
              " style='background-color: transparent; width: 100px; height: 20px;'>Text Box</textarea> " +
              "</div>" 

     document.getElementById('text_boxes').innerHTML += html_script;

     var java_script = "$(function () {" +
     "            var sh = 0;" +
     "            var sw = 0;" +
     "            $('#draggable" + textBoxName + "').draggable({" +
     "               drag: function (event, ui) {" +
     "                  dragposition = ui.position;" +
     "                  $('#" + textBoxName + "').attr('data-topx', dragposition.left);" +
     "                  $('#" + textBoxName + "').attr('data-topy', dragposition.top);" +
     "              }" +
     "        });" +
     "          $('#" + textBoxName + "').resizable({" +
     "              stop: function (event, ui) {" +
     "                 s = ui.size;" +
     "                 sh = s.height;" +
     "                 sw = s.width;" +
     "                 $('#" + textBoxName + "').attr('data-width', s.width);" +
     "                 $('#" + textBoxName + "').attr('data-height', s.height);" +
     "     }" +
     "  });" +
     "});"

     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.text = java_script;
     document.getElementById("text_boxes").appendChild(script);
 };
```

Im really sorry if anyone thinks its bad code but only been at it for a couple of months!

So, what Im trying to do it each time a user click an icon, a draggable box is produced. Then if the user procduces another box, they BOTH remain movable.

Im sure there is a better way of doing it with out generating a script for each box but I dont know that yet!

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: If you were to define the content statically, you could have many draggable and droppable calls with no issue.  I don't think it's a noconflict() issue, but an issue somewhere else...  To test you could copy the markup rendered to the page and try this out as a static reference.  Also, if the textboxName random number is the same value as something already existing, this will always be the problem.  You have to make sure 100% that it's different.  So are  you sure the second random number is different?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. If I create one textbox and save the layout then reload so the new box is already there in the DOM then create a new one they both work. It seems to be only when i 'inject' the two new elemets - the htnl for the box and its script.  I have checked the numbers are different but it insists on stopping the previous generated box.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several issues with your code.

**(1)** Don't define ID as random. More boxes = higher probability of conflicts. Instead just define counter before the function and update it inside, i.e.

```
var counter = 0;
function createTextBox() {
    var textBoxName = 'tb_' + counter;
    counter++
    // other code
```

**(2)** You are using jQuery, so take full advantage of it. For example this line:

```
document.getElementById('text_boxes').innerHTML += html_script;
```

should be

```
$( "#text_boxes" ).append( html_script );
```

Your entire `html_script` variable can be for example:

```
html_script = $( '<div></div>' );
html_script.attr( "id", "draggable"+textBoxName );
html_script.css({
    position : "absolute",
    top : 100
});
html_script.append( $( "<img></img>", { 
    src : "../../Images/next.png", 
    style : "cursor:pointer" 
});
...and so on
```

Even better: you should only set classes on your DOM elements and handle CSS separately.

**(3)** You are using `$(function(){...})` in your JavaScript. JQuery uses this to fire script when DOM is ready. But since ready event fires only once, then this script executes only once ( assuming `createTextBox()` was called before event was fired ). CODE INSIDE THIS FUNCTION WILL NEVER GET CALLED! That's why it doesn't work. Simple solution: remove `$(function(){...})` wrapping.

**(4)** Do not add JavaScript tags to DOM. It's JavaScript, you don't have to mess with DOM tree. Instead of

```
var java_script = "$(function () {" +
     "            var sh = 0;" +
...and so on
```

simply do:

```
var sh = 0;
var sw = 0;
$( "#draggable" + textBoxName ).draggable({
    drag : function(event, ui) {
        var dragposition = ui.position; // <--- missing var keyword
        ...and so on
```

**(5)** In several places you are missing `var` keyword. Variables defined without `var` keyword are global, visible to every other script. This may lead to conflicts.

Rule of thumb: always always use `var`. If you want to define global variable do this like that:

```
window.myVar = 5;
```

( note that `window` is a top object in browser ).

Comment: THANK YOU! I implemented what you suggested in points 2 and 3 and it now works. I like the way you re-code in point 2 and will work to do this. Thanks again!